# How can we interact with embedded html pages using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

Unable to interact with elements in the embedded html page inside the parent html

Hi,

The webpage i am automating has an embedded html page inside the parent page.

I am not able to interact with the elements present in the embedded page, it there a way to use them, i tried using switch to frame with the instance on  webelement but it is not working.

document.querySelector('s2a-shell').shadowRoot.querySelector('section > div').shadowRoot.querySelector('embed')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue, because `embed` element, that placed in shadow root, is actually `iframe`.

So to use it in Selenium, you should go inside `shadow_root` as you did via `JavaScript executor` and return this element.

Example in Java pseudo-code

```js
WebElement embed = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector(selector).shadowRoot.querySelector(...);"); // embed element
driver.switchTo().frame(embed);
driver.findElement(new By.ByCssSelector("yourSelector"));
```

If you want more concrete solution, please, provide html structure as code and language that you're using.

Comment: I have already tried this approach, its not really working

Comment: @Aditya so, provide me html structure to your element, so I would be able to help you

Comment: When i am copying the html from developers mode it is not capturing the elements in shadow dom or embedded html, So i have provided another link with bigger screenshot of the html structure